# Issue resizing a div background image with CSS

Tags: css, image, html, background, resize

I am working on a draft version of my website which uses a more responsive design than the original and have encountered a problem making my CSS rollover effect navbar buttons resize properly. I can get the divs to resize ok but not the .png images themselves.

Below is the code for the "Home" button. I set the div to resize to 11.5% because when it is displayed next to the other buttons they all have unique sizes and fit nicely within the parent div.

Any help much appreciated :) thanks for looking!

```
#homebut
{
display:inline-block;
width:158px;
height:40px;
max-width:11.5%;
max-height:100%;
text-align:center;
background:url(images/buttons/wawhomeroll.png) no-repeat 0 0;
background-position:center top;
background-size:auto;


}

#homebut:hover
{
background-position:0 -40px;
background-position:center bottom;

}

#homebut: span
{
position:absolute;
top: -999em;

}
```

Comment: if I recall - **background-size:100% 100%;** works - auto is the size of the image - and/or say **background-size: 100% auto** to keep aspect ratio

Comment: Awesome! Applying background-size: 100% auto; They are now scaling properly! seems to have done it! I just need to tinker with the hover attribute and images themselves now and i'll be all set. Thanks @RobSedgwick

Comment: Great stuff, Jay. Will throw it in as the answer. Interesting about  background-size:cover too from @rocknrollcanneverdie

Answer (score 1):

As comments `background-size:100% auto;`

```
#homebut {
   display:inline-block;
   width:158px;
   height:40px;
   max-width:11.5%;
   max-height:100%;
   text-align:center;
   background:url(images/buttons/wawhomeroll.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   background-position:center top;

   background-size:100% auto;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size: cover;`.

> **Cover** This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.